# Unable to get Solr Delta Import Index working

Tags: solr, lucene

These are the exact steps that I have taken to try and get delta import handler working. If I can provide any more information to help let me know. I have literally spent the entire friday night and today on this and I throw in the towel. Where have I gone wrong?

Added this line to the solrconfig:

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="config">/home/solr/data-config.xml</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

Then my data-config.xml looks like this:

```
<dataConfig>
  <dataSource type="FileDataSource" />
  <document>
    <entity 
      name="document" 
      processor="FileListEntityProcessor" 
      baseDir="/var/lib/data" 
      fileName=".*.xml$" 
      recursive="false" 
      rootEntity="false" 
      dataSource="null">
      <entity 
        processor="XPathEntityProcessor" 
        url="${document.fileAbsolutePath}" 
        useSolrAddSchema="true" 
        stream="true">
      </entity>
    </entity>
  </document>
</dataConfig>
```

Then in my var/lib/data folder I have a data.xml file that looks like this:

```
<add>
<doc>
        <field name="id">123</field>
        <field name="description">This is my long description</field>
        <field name="company">Google</field>
        <field name="location_name">England</field>
        <field name="date">2007-12-31 22:29:59</field>
        <field name="source">Google</field>
        <field name="url">www.google.com</field>
        <field name="latlng">45.17614,45.17614</field>
</doc>
</add>
```

Finally I then ran this command:

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/dataimport?command=delta-import&clean=false
```

And I get this result (failed):

```
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">1</int>
</lst>
<lst name="initArgs">
<lst name="defaults">
<str name="config">/home/solr/data-config.xml</str>
</lst>
</lst>
<str name="command">delta-import</str>
<str name="status">idle</str>
<str name="importResponse"/>
<lst name="statusMessages">
<str name="Time Elapsed">0:15:9.543</str>
<str name="Total Requests made to DataSource">0</str>
<str name="Total Rows Fetched">0</str>
<str name="Total Documents Processed">0</str>
<str name="Total Documents Skipped">0</str>
<str name="Delta Dump started">2012-11-17 17:32:56</str>
<str name="Identifying Delta">2012-11-17 17:32:56</str>
<str name="">Indexing failed. Rolled back all changes.</str>
<str name="Rolledback">2012-11-17 17:32:56</str>
</lst>
<str name="WARNING">
This response format is experimental. It is likely to change in the future. 
</str>
</response>
```

EDIT: This is what the tomcat.log says:

```
INFO: Starting Delta Import
Nov 18, 2012 12:48:46 PM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute
INFO: [] webapp=/solr path=/dataimport params={clean=false&command=delta-import} status=0 QTime=1 
Nov 18, 2012 12:48:46 PM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SimplePropertiesWriter readIndexerProperties
WARNING: Unable to read: dataimport.properties
Nov 18, 2012 12:48:46 PM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder doDelta
INFO: Starting delta collection.
Nov 18, 2012 12:48:46 PM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder collectDelta
INFO: Running ModifiedRowKey() for Entity: 84430688679548
Nov 18, 2012 12:48:46 PM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder collectDelta
INFO: Completed ModifiedRowKey for Entity: 84430688679548 rows obtained : 0
Nov 18, 2012 12:48:46 PM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder collectDelta
INFO: Completed DeletedRowKey for Entity: 84430688679548 rows obtained : 0
Nov 18, 2012 12:48:46 PM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder collectDelta
INFO: Completed parentDeltaQuery for Entity: 84430688679548
Nov 18, 2012 12:48:46 PM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder collectDelta
INFO: Running ModifiedRowKey() for Entity: document
Nov 18, 2012 12:48:46 PM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder collectDelta
INFO: Completed ModifiedRowKey for Entity: document rows obtained : 0
Nov 18, 2012 12:48:46 PM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder collectDelta
INFO: Completed DeletedRowKey for Entity: document rows obtained : 0
Nov 18, 2012 12:48:46 PM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder collectDelta
INFO: Completed parentDeltaQuery for Entity: document
Nov 18, 2012 12:48:46 PM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder doDelta
INFO: Delta Import completed successfully
```

Comment: you need to show solr log error message, it will have the details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Using_delta-import_command-1):

> The only EntityProcessor which supports delta is SqlEntityProcessor! The XPathEntityProcessor has not implemented it yet. So, unfortunately, there is no delta support for XML at this time.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, this is quite strange. I dont understand though, because there seems to be working exampels of delta imports working with XML:
http://www.andornot.com/blog/post/Sample-Solr-DataImportHandler-for-XML-Files.aspx

Comment: The document you linked is not about delta-imports. With full-import this will work.